# IE9 click order

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, internet-explorer-9

This code : http://jsfiddle.net/bYtTG/1/

Works *as I want* in FF, chrome and opera, but not IE : When you click on "Calculer", they all disable the button, except for IE.

Its seems that IE doesn't like me to focus+blur inputs (I do that to format some read-only textbox to currency format with telerik).

Any idea on how to fix this? I don't like onChange (plus, the Telerik controls allow you to use the keyboard up/down arrows to change an input value, which doesn't trigger the onChange event).

### html

```
<div>
    <input id="a" value="2" /><br />
    <input id="b" value="3" /><br />
    <input id="c" value="" class="inactif" /><br />
    <input id="d" value="5" /><br />
    <input id="e" value="7" class="inactif" /><br />
    <input id="total"><br /><br />
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="calculer" />
```

### js

$(document).ready(function () {

```
    $('div input').focus(function () {
        $('#btn').removeClass("inactif");
        $('#btn').attr('disabled', false);
    });


    $('#btn').click(function () {
        //L1-L2=L3
        Calculer('a', '+', 'b', 'c');
        Calculer('c', '-', 'd', 'total');
        Calculer('d', '+', 'e', 'total');

        //those line seems to be "ignored"
        $('#btn').delay(500).addClass("inactif");
        $('#btn').delay(200).attr('disabled', true);
    });

    function Calculer(idFacteur1, operande, idFacteur2, idResultat) {
        var val1 = parseInt($('#' + idFacteur1).val());
        var val2 = parseInt($('#' + idFacteur2).val());
        var res = 0;
        if (operande == "+") {
            res = val1 + val2;
        } else {
            res = val1 - val2;
        }
        $('#' + idResultat).val(res);
        $('#' + idResultat).focus().blur();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this with a `setTimeout`

```
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#btn').addClass("inactif");
        $('#btn').attr('disabled', true);
    }, 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just call the .change() event of the input item instead of doing focus().blur()? As long as Telerik recognizes that as a valid event for formatting, it will work fine for you.

Comment: Because replacing `.focus().blur()` with `.change()` doesn't trigger Telerik reformating of the input box : the input display (div overlay) stay blank, although the value of the input is good.